# Hide woocommerce products that are lower than a specified price

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to add custom args to all the Woocommerce Product queries to make them return only the products that are above a specified price. (>10$)

I would like to use an action on my theme's function.php file.

Any clue? Thank you very much!

Comment: Use [pre_get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) filter with meta_query for pricing filtering.

Comment: any example would be grateful , thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', function($query){
    if ( !is_admin() and is_product_category() and $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $meta_query = $query->get('meta_query');
        $meta_query['relation'] = 'AND';

        $meta_query[] = [
            'key'   => '_price',
            'value' => 100,
            'compare' => '<',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
        ];

        $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for your responce. i am adding this code in function.php file with no effects on the product list... although it looks right

Comment: And you replace the value for price comparing in meta_query to value you want?

Comment: What type of the page? Is it product category page? On may be is main page?

Comment: product category page... you can have a look at www.andriashome.com/blog/shop

Comment: Try to use __regular_price_ key instead __price_.

Comment: @glutaminefree, I think the right syntax is `$meta_query[] = array(...)` and not with `[...]` ?

Comment: also, I would like to add something to the conditional statement, `( is_shop() || is_product_category())`

Answer (score 1):

Add this function to the bottom of your `functions.php` and change the number to the correct one.

Hooking to `woocommerce_product_query` directly.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'react2wp_hide_products_higher_than_zero' );
function react2wp_hide_products_higher_than_zero( $q ){
   $meta_query = $q->get( 'meta_query' );
   $meta_query[] = array(
      'key'       => '_price',
      'value'     => 10, // CHANGE THIS TO THE NUMBER YOU WANT
      'compare'   => '>'
   );
   $q->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
}
```

Taken from: https://react2wp.com/woocommerce-hide-products-without-price-simple-fix/